# Javascript function won't return variable correctly

Tags: javascript

I was becoming confident in my javascript skills and then this simple problem has got me stumped. I call this function and whether or not `validEmail` is false, the value returned is always false. What am I doing wrong?

```
function tryEmail(email)
{
    var validEmail = false;
    console.log("function:tryEmail, param: " + email);
    $.post("php/users-profs/tryEmail.php",
    {
        email:email
    },
    function(data)
    {
        console.log("function:tryEmail-post, data: " + data);
        if(data === "valid")
            validEmail = true;
    });
    return validEmail;
}
```

Comment: because the return happens before the ajax request is finished, ajax calls are asynchronous, the success call does not get executed here it just gets set.

Comment: You were caught (like many others) by the A in Ajax. "Asynchronous" = "not at the same time".

Comment: You _can_ make a synchronous call to XMLHttpRequest - but when you do, your script will hang until either timeout, or success. Helpful information at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

Comment: So I should probably use a deferred object then?